# Jmeter Multi Tenant

Tags: jmeter

Stuck on a multi tenant load test.
I have 10 sites and each site will run the same exact test with the same users.
I first created the script with 10 thread groups (1 for each tenant)and works but when editing the script it takes a while so I'm trying to make it more dynamic.

Now I have 1 thread group and I created 2 CSV data set configs. 1 CSV for users(sharing mode: current thread group) and 1 CSV for the 10 tenants(sharing mode: All Threads), this is working but user 1 hits Tenant 1, then user 2 hits Tenant 2 and so on. I can't figure out is I want user 1 to login to all 10 tenants then user 2 login to all 10 tenants and so on

Answer (score 1):

I tried executing a scenario similar to the one you have mentioned in the question with minor change. I used sharing mode for users' CSV file as **Current thread** and loop count of thread group as 2.

1 Thread Group with,

```
Number of Threads: 5
Loop Count: 2
```

CSV Data Set Configuration:

```
1. 1 CSV (link.csv) with 5 links. Sharing mode: All threads
2. 1 CSV (users.csv) with 2 user credentials. Sharing mode: Current thread
```

Configured HTTP Request Sampler to accept links from link.csv and user credentials from users.csv

Result:

```
1. 5 requests with user 1 for each of the 5 links.
2. 5 requests with user 2 for each of the 5 links.
```

This configuration did what you were expecting.

I also tried the above scenario with sharing mode as Current thread group and the script took user credentials randomly for the requests. Whereas with sharing mode as Current thread group all five links take first user sequentially and execute and then the five links execute with the second user.